# Laravel Error screen, what file throws the error and what file to fix?

Tags: laravel, error-handling

I really like to understand where the problem is in my project and I love Laravel, but at the same time it makes it so difficult to find WHERE the problem comes from.

I don't understand if is a lack of knowledge on my part (perhaps so) or if I need to have some magic wand to understand WHAT FILE is throwing the error.

I'm currently working with 3 classes:

1. `HttpClientContract.php` in `App\Services\Http` folder
2. `HttpClient.php` in `App\Services\Http` folder
3. `HttpClientServiceProvider.php` in `App\Providers` folder

Probably I misnamed something or called a wrong path but the error I have is the following:

[image]

From here I do understand I called `Class App\Services\HttpClientContract` that does not exist, fine. But WHERE did I do that mistake? :(

It says is in the `...src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteSignatureParameters.php` which is probably the sub container Class or so, but I do not know where **MY** mistake is.

---

**[edit]**

Of course being a `RouteSignatureParameters.php` I can think of `routes/web.php` file. But I'll give you another example:

In this [Laracast lesson](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018/episodes/21) at minute `7:20` the `routes/web.php` is composed of this:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    dd(app('example'));
});
```

The `Example` Class is not imported nor bound to the App Container therefore this errors fires this:

[image]

The file I need to fix is `web.php` in the `routes` folder, but Laravel Error handling doesn't tell me this, so how do I figure it out?

Is there a way to show up in what file actually needs fixing?

Comment: did you run: composer dump-autoload ?

Comment: Yes, my question is not "why I have this error?" but "what file is the one I have to fix?"

Comment: You need to include the classes at the top of your file: `use App\Services\HttpClientContract`

Comment: You can try outside in, to find out the error. So which URL you are trying to access, and check to which controller that route has been mapped to. That's where you will find the wrong import.

Comment: Ok @rpm192 I know what the error is and why I have it. My question is WHERE is the file which is to be changed?

Comment: @nakov so Laravel Error does not tell me? I have to guess basically?

Comment: @Mr.Web it does tell you that you have wrong route signature. So it is not guessing, as you already have the URL in your browser.

Comment: Can you show your route code for this url? I supose something is not correctly configured there.

Comment: Post your provider code please

Comment: isn't it suppose to be `App\Services\Http\HttpClientContract` class? I think you missed the `Http` directory in the class path.

Comment: You should look trough the call stack on the left

Comment: The way that helps me know the folder where the file with the error is, is that i look in the thrown error `App\Services\HttpClientContract` and i know that the `HttpClientContract` is in folder other than `App\Services` so your error occurs in that folder. In general the error `Class XXX\YYY\SomeClass does not exist` and `SomeClass` location is a folder other than `XXX\YYY` so the error occurs in `XXX\YYY` folder look at what you changed there :)

Comment: Ok thank you guys, please see my edit

Comment: Sometimes it helps to click on "application frames"

Comment: Ok so the final result is that I basically have to become more acquainted with the framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually laravel does tell you which file is responsible for the error. The red box in below image is your whole call stack (backtracing) and the file that generated the error is somewhere between that
[image: image of laravel error page]

To make it easier you can change the call stack only to application frame and it'll be easier to find the file where you made the mistake.
[image: image of laravel error call stack]

and this is the 35th line of `App\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php` file

```
35        app('example');
36
37        return view('home');
```

When you make syntax error or something similar it'll be straight forward (check the image, just one file), but if the error is like that you made is different because the error didn't happened until the non-existent class was being tried to instantiate which is why you get a long list of call stack.
[image: image of laravel error screen]